# How to check docker-compose installed or not using Ansible?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible

I am doing a project where , I have to run docker-compose using Ansible.

So How to find the docker-compose is already present in host or not, if not i am going to do conditional check and then install docker-compose on the host using Ansible first, and then run docker-compose.

So , How one can find docker-compose already exists in the host environment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into this [example](http://en.enisozgen.com/ansible-check-is-command-exist/), which is similar to what you are looking for

```
- name: Check docker-compose installation play
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Check is docer-compose installed
    shell: command -v docker-compose >/dev/null 2>&1
    register: is_docker_compose_install
    ignore_errors: yes
  
  - debug: msg="{{ is_docker_compose_install.rc }}" # it returns rc 0 if installed or 127 if not
  - debug: var=is_docker_compose_install
```

`is_docker_compose_install.rc` will returns `0` if installed.

output

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "0"
}
```

So if you want to run particular command only if compose is installed then the below will work

```
- name: Check docker-compose installation play
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Check is docer-compose installed
    shell: command -v docker-compose >/dev/null 2>&1
    register: is_docker_compose_install
    ignore_errors: yes
  - debug: msg="{{ is_docker_compose_install.rc }}" # it returns rc 1
  - debug: var=is_docker_compose_install
  - name: Run only if compose is installed
    shell: command docker-compose --version
    register: print_version
    ignore_errors: yes
    when: is_docker_compose_install.rc == 0
  - debug: msg="{{ print_version.stdout }}"
```

output if installed

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "docker-compose version 1.25.5, build unknown"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to elaborate a bit further on your question:

> So How to find the docker-compose is already present in host or not, if not i am going to do conditional check and then install docker-compose on the host using Ansible first, and then run docker-compose

You don't need to do any of this.

Simply create a task that installs docker-compose (I assume by using the [pip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pip_module.html) module) and then create the next task with your docker-compose commands.

Most Ansible modules (with notable exceptions) are idempotent, which means that Ansible will check on your behalf if docker-compose already exists on your target machine and install it in case it is not installed.

Simply put, you don't need to verify nor create any conditionals to install docker-compose, just use the corresponding Ansible module and Ansible will do the magic for you.